# Puppet Accidently deleted etckeeper-commit-pre and etckeeper-commit-post is there a way to regenerate these files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, puppet

Basically I deleted these files while doing some clean up in my puppet directory.
Now when I run @app: puppet apply /some/file I got an error stating these file where missing. (of course)

So I created two new files and I got this:

err: Could not run command from prerun_command: Execution of '/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre' returned 1: 
err: Could not run command from postrun_command: Execution of '/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post' returned 1

Any hints would be great thanks
Thanks
Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Puppet "[filebucket](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/man/filebucket.html)" enabled, you could look through the logs to find the hash of the removed file, then recover from that.

Otherwise go to your backups, or reinstall the package they come from.

Comment: I'm very new to puppet so how would I know what package installed them?

Comment: Those are not part of Puppet; they must have been added by something else - your site packages or something like that, I fear.